# jQuery toggle class on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have list of links, and if you click on any of them, it will toggle show/hide text below it in separate div. Also it hides all other divs if one of them is shown
This code manages it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('.hideshow').click(function () {
        $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle('').siblings('.targetDiv').hide('');
});});
```

And this is what the link looks like

```
<a class="hideshow" target="1"><div class="cennikPlus"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></div>Something something</a>
```

What i need to do is to change

```
fa-plus-square
```

to

```
fa-minus-square
```

when open and back, when closed.
I found "toggleClass" which should be useful in this case, but I am not sure how to select i inside div inside a

Can you help me with this?

Also the website is [here](http://glanis.virpo.sk/cennik/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `<i>` and call toggleClass

```
$(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square")
```

Answer (score 2):

To select the `<i>` inside your tag, you just do this:

```
$( this ).find( 'i' )
```

you can chain it all together to toggle the class--

```
$( this ).find( 'i' ).toggleClass( 'fa-plus-square fa-minus-square' )
```

and for siblings, if you want them all to have the class 'fa-minus-square', you do this:

```
$( this ).siblings().find( 'i' ).removeClass( 'fa-plus-square' ).addClass( 'fa-minus-square' )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using parent - child selectors in jQuery is quite simple...

```
$("a > div > i")
```

will select the i element, that is a child of the div element, that is a child of the a element.  http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp.

If the elements are not going to be direct descendants, as in your example, remove the greater than sign.

```
$("a div i")
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright... this is my first time adding jQuery code to existing one so I tried to do something, it didnt work so i thought i did it wrong, but only mistake was selecting "li" instead of "i" element Solution was to add this line before the last line:

```
$(this).children('div').children('i').toggleClass("fa-plus-square fa-minus-square");
```