# toggle class not replacing the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some font awesome icons like this one:

```
<a class="allarme" id="allarme1" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i> <!--<span>Avvia</span>-->
</a>
```

I want to replace the icon on click so I need to change the `i` class. For example from `fa-toggle-off` to `fa-toggle-on`

So I wrote this peice of code:

```
$('.allarme').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass(".fa-toggle-off .fa-toggle-on");
});
```

Console tells me that the event is fired correctly but the class is not toggled. I tried to check on [SO previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038189/jquery-toggle-class-on-child-element) and I have found the same code as correct solution on another question. What do I miss?

Comment: Is it a typo that you left the `.`'s in the `toggleClass` call?

Comment: it's a typo in the original code that I didn't notice... :) OMG! Thanks @Stryner

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-toggle");` where it adds it if not there and remove it if it's there?

Comment: @LGSon you have to remove the -off and add the -on to replace the icon. It is a switch between on and off.

Comment: Yeah .. sorry, what I meant to say was there shouldn't be 2 class names

Comment: @LGSon providing two classes you toggle both in the same time. If it is there it removes or viceversa for each of the arguments See also the answer I mentioned in my question

Comment: What does it semantically mean for an element to have both `fa-toggle-on` and `fa-toggle-off` applied at the same time? If that situation doesn't make sense, then do you really need both classes? (eg, do you need 2 levers to represent 2 states?)

Comment: @Katana314 it never happens to have both classes applied at the same time since on load the element has one of the two classes. So this code will always trigger to remove one class and apply the other. If you see my code I start with -off so my code will remove it and add -on. The second click will remove -on (toggle it) and add -off (second toggle)

Comment: @LelioFaieta I agree the code seems pretty secure now. The point I'm making is that it's like using `int` for a variable that should only ever have two possible states (and should be `bool`). How I would design it is that either the `fa` has `fa-toggle-off` and is off, or it doesn't, and is on. Then it's literally impossible for a bad coder to get it into an "illegal" state; just perhaps an unwanted one.

Comment: @Katana314 This two classes are designed (not by me) to work this way since they are used to display font awesome icons on my site. So I am "obliged" to use this logic. I agree with you on the theory. I'd do the same but this is the way font awesome works

Comment: @LelioFaieta OK, fair enough; compatibility is definitely above all else. A snobbish person like me could probably "correct" the icon display CSS to use one image when the class is not there, and another if the class is not. Not a major concern though and it is readable, so this should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery.toggleClass()` takes up to 2 arguments:

1. Class name
2. State

If you wish to remove a class, a add it back each time you click on something, you simply need to provide the class name

```
$('.allarme').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-toggle");
});
```

If you wish to interchange two different classes, your code will require more logic:

```
$('.allarme').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $i = $( this ).find( 'i' )

    if ( $i.hasClass( 'fa-toggle-off' ) ) {
        $i.removeClass( 'fa-toggle-off' ).addClass( 'fa-toggle-on' )
    } else {
        $i.removeClass( 'fa-toggle-on' ).addClass( 'fa-toggle-off' )
    }
});
```

I suggest that you use the first approach. It is much cleaner, both from a JavaScript point of view, but from a functional CSS point of view as well.

Comment: Thanks but the issue was just a typo and is already fixed. Anyway note that I am doing too all you do in just one line ;)